# uwp Expression node fade in animation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp, windows-composition-api

I am using the sample on Windows UI dev labs sample gallery. And I used ShyHeader example to put in my app, but I am not using exactly the same code but I actually edited the example according to own needs.
My question is how can I use expression node to fade in a specific XAML element in correspondence to the scroll viewer, I am able to fade out an element with the scroll viewer. but I am not being able to fade in an element from opacity 0 -> opacity 1.
**here is my code.**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyAdaptiveView Margin="0,300,0,0"
                  x:Name="AllVideosGridView"/>
        <Grid x:Name="Header" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <FlipView x:Name="MainFlipView" 
            </FlipView>
            <Grid Background="Blue" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.5" Name="FrontGrid">

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**page loaded method**

the only important piece of code is only at the very end of this method, the last 4, 5 lines, you can see I am able to fade out element by doing **1- progresNode** but my attempt to fade in another element ( frontVisual ) by doing **0+ progressNode** doesn't work and frontVisual actually remains at 0 opacity even after I scroll.
    private void ShyView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the PropertySet that contains the scroll values from MyScrollViewer
            _scrollerPropertySet = ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet(MyScrollViewer);
            _compositor = _scrollerPropertySet.Compositor;

```
        // Create a PropertySet that has values to be referenced in the ExpressionAnimations below
        _props = _compositor.CreatePropertySet();
        _props.InsertScalar("progress", 0);
        _props.InsertScalar("clampSize", 150);
        _props.InsertScalar("scaleFactor", 0.7f);

        // Get references to our property sets for use with ExpressionNodes
        var scrollingProperties = _scrollerPropertySet.GetSpecializedReference<ManipulationPropertySetReferenceNode>();
        var props = _props.GetReference();
        var progressNode = props.GetScalarProperty("progress");
        var clampSizeNode = props.GetScalarProperty("clampSize");
        var scaleFactorNode = props.GetScalarProperty("scaleFactor");

        // Create a blur effect to be animated based on scroll position
        var blurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect()
        {
            Name = "blur",
            BlurAmount = 0.0f,
            BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
            Optimization = EffectOptimization.Balanced,
            Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source")
        };

        var blurBrush = _compositor.CreateEffectFactory(
            blurEffect,
            new[] { "blur.BlurAmount" })
            .CreateBrush();

        blurBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", _compositor.CreateBackdropBrush());

        // Create a Visual for applying the blur effect
        _blurredBackgroundImageVisual = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        _blurredBackgroundImageVisual.Brush = blurBrush;
        _blurredBackgroundImageVisual.Size = new Vector2((float)Header.ActualWidth, (float)Header.ActualHeight);

        // Insert the blur visual at the right point in the Visual Tree
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Header, _blurredBackgroundImageVisual);

        // Create and start an ExpressionAnimation to track scroll progress over the desired distance
        ExpressionNode progressAnimation = EF.Clamp(-scrollingProperties.Translation.Y / clampSizeNode, 0, 1);
        _props.StartAnimation("progress", progressAnimation);

        // Create and start an ExpressionAnimation to animate blur radius between 0 and 15 based on progress
        ExpressionNode blurAnimation = EF.Lerp(0, 15, progressNode);
        _blurredBackgroundImageVisual.Brush.Properties.StartAnimation("blur.BlurAmount", blurAnimation);

        // Get the backing visual for the header so that its properties can be animated
        Visual headerVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Header);

        // Create and start an ExpressionAnimation to clamp the header's offset to keep it onscreen
        ExpressionNode headerTranslationAnimation = EF.Conditional(progressNode < 1, 0, -scrollingProperties.Translation.Y - clampSizeNode);
        headerVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", headerTranslationAnimation);

        // Create and start an ExpressionAnimation to scale the header during overpan
        ExpressionNode headerScaleAnimation = EF.Lerp(1, 1.25f, EF.Clamp(scrollingProperties.Translation.Y / 50, 0, 1));
        headerVisual.StartAnimation("Scale.X", headerScaleAnimation);
        headerVisual.StartAnimation("Scale.Y", headerScaleAnimation);

        //Set the header's CenterPoint to ensure the overpan scale looks as desired
        headerVisual.CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(Header.ActualWidth / 2), (float)Header.ActualHeight, 0);

        // Get the backing visual for the photo in the header so that its properties can be animated
        Visual photoVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(MainFlipView);

        // Create and start an ExpressionAnimation to opacity fade out the image behind the header
        ExpressionNode imageOpacityAnimation = 1 - progressNode;
        photoVisual.StartAnimation("opacity", imageOpacityAnimation);

        // Get the front visual for the photo in the header so that its properties can be animated
        Visual frontVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(FrontGrid);

        // Create and start an ExpressionAnimation to opacity fade out the image behind the header
        ExpressionNode imageOpacityAnimation2 = 0 + progressNode;
        frontVisual.StartAnimation("opacity", imageOpacityAnimation2);
    }
```

**Note** the behavior I actually want is that when I scroll down then **FlipView** should fade out and when I scroll up to the top it should fade in, which is working perfectly, but along with it I want **FrontGrid** to be exactly opposite, i.e: fade in on scroll down and fade out on scroll up.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression looks OK.

Note the `Opacity` you are animating with Composition is the `Opacity` of `Visual`. However, the `Opacity` of `0.5` you are setting on `FrontGrid` XAML is from `UIElement`. Doing so will break the Composition opacity expression animation.

The fix is simple - Try getting the `Visual` of your `FrontGrid` right after `InitializeComponent` and set its `Opacity` to `0.5` there (i.e. `frontVisual.Opacity = 0.5`) instead of setting it in XAML.

---

You will see this kind of "weird" behaviors starting from the Anniversary Update, due to a *XAML-Composition Interop Behavior change*.

For a full explanation, please read this [official document](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/wiki/XAML-Composition-Interop-Behavior-Changes).

In short, XAML doesn't know if Composition has changed the `Opacity`, it still thinks it should be `0.5` as it was last set. So it will try to override and cause the animation to fail. This happens to a few more properties like `Offset` and `Size` too.

My advice is if you go Composition, try going Composition all the way. :)